# Yeoman copy directory with templating

Tags: templates, directory, yeoman, scaffolding

How can I copy multiple files in a whole folder recursively while applying templating ?
I found answers for copying folders without templating, templating individual files but not batch templating.

I currently do :

```js
'use strict';
const Generator = require('yeoman-generator');
module.exports = class extends Generator {
  writing() {
    this.fs.write(
       this.destinationPath('public'),
       ejs.render(this.fs.read(this.templatePath('public')), 
       {
         webPageTitle : 'great web application',
       }),
     );
  );
}
```

where the public directory contains many files including `index.html` :

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
    <title><%= webPageTitle %></title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

but yeoman throws an error :

```
Error generator-name
~/Documents/yo-test/generator-name/generators/app/templates/public doesn't exist
```

I understand yeoman expects a file and not a folder. I do not want to process each file individually. This would be both cumbersome and more difficult to maintain in the long run.

What is the right approach for both copying a complete folder with its subfolders and in the mean time batch templating all its files with yeoman ?

Answer (score 0):

The right way I found :

```js
    this.fs.copyTpl(
      this.templatePath('public'),
      this.destinationPath('public'),
      {
        webPageTitle : 'great web application',
      }
    );
```

that copies the whole `public` folder and applies the templating substitution wherever possible.
As a result, the `index.html` is being applied the expected substitution during the recursive batch copy process of the `public` folder.